# runtime error: signed integer overflow: 2147453785 + 36049 cannot be represented in type 'int'

Tags: c++, runtime-error

I get the following error on running the code below:
I am trying to solve a LeetCode problem and I get this error. I changed the datatype from **int** to **long long int** but I still get it. Can someone please help me ?

```
Line 130: Char 39: runtime error: signed integer overflow: 2147453785 + 36049 cannot be represented in type 'int' (stl_numeric.h)
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_numeric.h:139:39
```

The code I have written is:

```
class Solution {
public:
    int minimumAverageDifference(vector<int>& nums) {
        long long int n = nums.size();
        long long int sumfromstart = 0;
        long long int sumfromend = accumulate(nums.begin(),nums.end(),0);
        int res = INT_MAX;
        int index = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            sumfromstart += nums[i];
            sumfromend -= nums[i];
            int a = sumfromstart/(i+1);
            int b = (i == n-1) ? 0 : sumfromend/(n-i-1);
            int avg = abs(a-b);
            if(avg < res)
            {
                res = avg;
                index = i;
            }
        }
        return index;
    }
};
```

Comment: This is a bit of a trap. In the call to `std::accumulate`, the last argument doesn't just give the starting value; it gives the type of the accumulator. So change that `0` to `0LL`.

Comment: Please don't use scam coding websites to learn C++. They won't teach you anything good. Here is a much better source of knowledge: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: When you asked this question on the LeetCode forums, what answers did you get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`std::accumulate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) is a templated function that in this case is defined as follows *(prior to C++20)*:

```cpp
template< class InputIt, class T >
T accumulate( InputIt first, InputIt last, T init );
```

Since `accumulate` returns a value of type `T`, and the type of the third parameter (`T init`) is of type `T`, whatever type you pass as the third parameter will be used to accumulate the result value. In your case, that's type `int`, because:

```cpp
        //                                This is a literal of type `int`
        //                                                            ▼
        long long int sumfromend = accumulate(nums.begin(),nums.end(),0);
        //                       ▲
        //  Implicit cast from `int` to `long long int`
```

You can fix this by using a literal of type `long long` *(that's the short-form for `long long int`)* instead, which is defined by appending 2 `l` or `L` characters to the end of a number literal, like this:

```cpp
        //                            This is a literal of type `long long`
        //                                                            ▼▼▼
        long long int sumfromend = accumulate(nums.begin(),nums.end(),0LL);
        //                       ▲
        //              No typecast required
```

Comment: Thank u for the knowledge. I didn't know much about the accumulate() function